# Rails3 ajax callback has empty xhr

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm seeing some strange behaviour with my Rails3 app.  Note that I'm using the jQuery version of `rails.js`

From `rails.js` starting at line :49

```
 error: function (xhr, status, error) {
   el.trigger('ajax:failure', [xhr, status, error]);
   alert('error in: ' + xhr.responseText ); 
 }
```

From my jQuery code to execute after the form.

```
 .bind('ajax:failure', function(xhr, status, error) {
    alert('error in: ' + xhr.responseText );
 })
```

In the alert in rails.js shows the expected return text, but the alert my callback shows:

```
  error in: undefined
```

So it doesn't appear that xhr is being sent to the callback correctly.  Am I doing something wrong, or is this an issue with `rails.js`?

Further testing shows that this applies for both the `ajax:failure` and `ajax:success` callbacks.  With the `ajax:success` call back the server response is in `status`, so I didn't notice the behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the jQuery docs on `.trigger()`:

> "The event object is always passed as
>   the first parameter to an event
>   handler, but if additional parameters
>   are specified during a .trigger() call
>   as they are here, these parameters
>   will be passed along to the handler as
>   well."

The example they give is:

`$('#foo').bind('custom', function(event, param1, param2) {
  alert(param1 + "\n" + param2);
});
$('#foo').trigger('custom', ['Custom', 'Event']);`

So I updated:
`.bind('ajax:failure', function(xhr, status, error)`

to:
`.bind('ajax:failure', function(event, xhr, status, error)`

And it's working fine now.  Clearly my mistake